# How can i access user values for my application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

> When i print `req.user` in `'/login'` it works good but when i use the same code in other actions (`'/'`, `'/profile`, etc...) it is not working

```
//GET login
router.get('/login', (req, res, next)=>{

  var messageLoginErr = req.flash('signinError')
  res.render('login', {messages : messageLoginErr}); 
});


router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  session: false,
  //successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  //failureFlash: true,
}),
  function(req, res, next){
    res.json({email : req.user.email})
  }
);

// // /* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({email : req})
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your passport setup, that's where my assumption of the issue might be:

```
/* assuming you're using passport-local along with passport, as well as the 
standard library express-session, and have defined a User model */
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const User = require('./models/user');


passport.use(User.createStrategy());

// use static authenticate method of model in LocalStrategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));

/* this is where I think the issue might be, that maybe the User hasn't been serialized */
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

I'm new, so I couldn't comment asking for clarification. If anyone wants to edit, go right ahead.